# how to manage memory in potentially long lists in android?

Tags: android

Let's say I have a list or recycler view that shows data pulled from a web api or local storage. This list is potentially very large, and the user may potentially keep scrolling down to load more data. What is the best practice for managing memory in this situation? Do I need to worry about `OutOfMemoryException`'s if I just store all these items in memory?

Comment: While complex, you could consider [the Paging component of the Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging).

Comment: @CommonsWare But what if the user keeps swiping down to load more pages? I think paging will prevent all the data from being loaded at once, but unless the data at the beginning of the list is being freed, I'll eventually run out of memory.

Comment: My understanding is that Paging frees memory from the older items. It keeps a range of data, around the user's current position, and frees up past items to make room for new ones.

Comment: How large is "very large" - millions of records?

Comment: @Joni How large do you think the data would have to be for this to be an issue?

Comment: Depends on the case. Thousands of records is fine, tens of thousands is probably ok, hundreds of thousands is likely pushing your luck

Comment: @Joni Let's say it was millions of records. How could this be handled?

Comment: Then you implement paging and make sure only a few pages are kept in memory. But you also need to think about if putting a million items in a list is a reasonable user interface. How will users find anything? You'll need search, filters, sorting. It's a very different problem compared to having a few hundred items